# expect -timeout vs. "set timeout" in expect: Different behavior

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, expect

I was testing a expect script and found two different behaviors when using `set timeout` vs. `expect -timeout`. Here is a simple example

`response.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sleep 2
echo hello
```

`test1.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./response.sh
set timeout -1
expect {
    timeout {
        send_user "timeout\n"
    } "hello" {
        send_user "received hello\n"
    }
}
```

Output (works as expected):

```
spawn ./response.sh
hello
received hello
```

however when I use the `-timeout` flag in expect I never get a response back no matter what value I use for timeout:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./response.sh
expect -timeout 1 {
    timeout {
        send_user "timeout\n"
    } "hello" {
        send_user "received hello\n"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
spawn ./response.sh
```

I am expecting `timeout` to be also printed in stdout. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is explained fully in the Stack Overflow post
[Why doesn't this expect handle timeout or eof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405028/why-doesnt-this-expect-handle-timeout-or-eof).

In short, the `-timeout` flag should be used prior to the
Expect's pattern,
not on the actions. With this flag you have signaled to override the
global `timeout` variable, but that's all.

Your code should be re-arranged with `-timeout 1` following
the braces, rather than before.

See the linked post for an example and fuller explanations.